# Rename child directories

Tags: powershell

Very first powershell experience and want to rename files and directories that starts with 50 to 40 inside of my rank folder

Initially I tried this

```
foreach($Directory in Get-ChildItem 'D:\Issues\' -Recurse -Directory)
{
    Rename-Item $Directory -NewName $($Directory.Name -replace "50","40")
}
```

But it also tries with the folders and even tries with the directories that doesn't have a 50 in it

second time i tried with

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Rename-Item {$_.FullName -replace '50','40'}
```

but this error comes in

> Rename-Item : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$_.FullName -replace '70','80''. At line:1 char:26

What Am I actually missing??

I have tried with 2 more Commands and it actually works but brings errors in red

For Files

```
foreach($File in Get-ChildItem 'D:\Issues\' -Recurse -file)
{
    Rename-Item $file -NewName $($_.Name -replace "50","40")
}
```

Errors

> Rename-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NewName' because it is an empty string. At line:3 char:32

For Directories

```
foreach($Directory in Get-ChildItem 'D:\Issues\' -Recurse -Directory)
{
    Rename-Item $Directory -NewName $($Directory.Name -replace "50","40")
}
```

Comment: Have tried with another 2 commands

Comment: `Rename-Item -NewName`, and if you want to rename specific items you need to filter for those items instead of shotgun-renaming everything.

Comment: Thanks @AnsgarWiechers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to filter `Get-ChildItem` to return only the items you want to rename. This can be done using the `Include` param:

```
Get-ChildItem D:\Issues -Include 50* -Recurse | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '50','40'}
```